Spring batch 5.x JpaPagingItemReader Adding "Top ?" to teradata query
I have a spring batch application that was running fine in spring batch 3.x, then it was upgraded to 5.x and it started to fail with:

Syntax error, expected something like an integer or a decimal number between the 'top' keyword and '?'.

The query is a simple
Select * from table_name

JpaPagingItemReader
JpaPagingItemReader r = new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<SomeEntity>()
                .name(someName)
                .entityMangerFactory(someEntityManagerFactory)
                .queryProvider(queryProvider())
                .pageSize(50000)
                .build();
return r;

queryProvider
JpaNativeQueryProvided<SomeEntity> provider = new JpaNativeQueryProvided<>();
provider.setSqlQuery("Select * from table_name;");
provider.setEntityClass(SomeEntity.class);
return provider;

The query is printed as:
Hibernate:
Select top ? * from table_name;

It seems that JPA or Hibernate is adding Top ? to the query, however I have no idea where it is expecting the value from.
I have made some changes related to spring batch 3.x to 5.x, and started to use hibernate-community-dialects for teradata, but the issue persists.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

Please provide configuration of the JpaPagingItemReader

@Vikram, I have added the JpaPagingItemReader configuration.
